# How to update a column depending on the overall rows of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing a colunm parentId (which has no constraint it may happens that this id does not exists , bacause of bad data !!!).
I have two separate things I would like to do 
Add a bit column IsChild 
- Contains true only if it has a ParentId and this one actually exists in my table
Add a bit column IsParent
- Contains true only if it has referencing child

I come up with something similar to :

```
UPDATE MyTable
  Set IsParent = 1
  WHERE Id in (select distinct parentId from MyTable) and IsParent = 0
UPDATE MyTable
  Set IsChild = 1
  WHERE parentId in (select id from MyTable) and IsChild = 0
```

But It is quite slow !!! Any idea how we can make it faster

**Bonus Question** : MyTable is a temporal table 
If we can update all fields at once to not create as many entries as statement

Comment: add an index to parentId?

Answer (score 1):

You can try an update join.  This would be ideal if `MyTable` had indices on both the `Id` and `parentId` columns.

```
UPDATE t1
SET IsParent = 1
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.parentId
WHERE isParent = 0

UPDATE t1
SET IsChild = 1
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t1.parentId = t2.Id
WHERE isChild = 0
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it in one pass ?

Comment: You could always do the two updates within a single transaction.